# Dynamically generated images, fetched using POST

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I need to dynamically load images inside a JSP. I've tried the
`<img src="servletUrl?p1=x&p2=y"/>`, but the problem is that the URL is too long to be sent using GET.

I'm now performing a POST call. From the servlet I'm generating a pie chart image, based on the params I send. The image is not persisted, so I can't return something like "images/image1.jpg" and set that as src of the image.

So I'm returning the image as a byte array and setting the appropriate image content type.

My question is: once I have the image bytes in javascript, how do I display them in the corresponding img tag?

This is my AJAX call:

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: params,
        onComplete: function(request) {
                    alert(request.responseText);      
        }
});
```

Comment: Why is the URL too long? That seems a bit odd...

Comment: hey, can you fiddle it out...that'd help

Comment: @beerbajay: because one of the parameters is a JSONized document, with lots of fields. It's a document that is not yet persisted and based on the values the user inputs in the various fields a piechart is generated and returned from the servlet.

Comment: In which browsers should this be running?

Comment: @Andreas: first place, in FF. But after I get it running in FF, I would also like to get it running in IE9 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't try this my self but it should work.
You could create an image and set its src using a [dataUrl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data%3a_URL). You will have to convert the `byte[]` in to a base64 encoded string for this to work.

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: params,
        onComplete: function(response) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + response;

            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's solution from top of my head, should work in all browsers:

Instead of AJAX and `<img>` tag, use an `<iframe>` pre-filled with form with hidden fields with all the necessary POST parameters and with `onload` handler set to submit this form to image serving script. Make this script return pure image that will be displayed in this iframe keeping rest of your page intact.